# S3 Upload file - Method not allowed

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload image to S3 bucket, but i'm getting this error.

```
 "Code: MethodNotAllowed",
              "Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.",
              "Method: PUT",
              "ResourceType: OBJECT",
```

my route is POST, i need post route to get request for file, i tryed to changed it to PUT but i'm getting same error.

ENV info

```
S3_KEY=*********
S3_SECRET=********
S3_BUCKET=my-bucket-name
S3_REGION=eu-central-1
S3_ENDPOINT=http://s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

uploading function

```
  const fileBuffer = await sharp(payload.image.tmpPath)
      .resize({ height: 1400, width: 800, fit: 'inside' })
      .toBuffer()

      const s3 = Drive.use('s3')

      const result = await s3.put(payload.image.tmpPath!, fileBuffer)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Endpoint, SDK, code snippet etc.

Comment: Hello, i updated my post. and added more info. I'm using adonis framework

Comment: What is `Drive.use`?

Comment: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/drive#s3-driver

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform Amazon S3 operations using JavaScript, then use the offical ***AWS SDK for JavaScript V3***. You can find this AMazon S3 code example in the official AWS Code Lib here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/javascript_3_s3_code_examples.html

Look at the example under **Upload an object to a bucket**.